# Append Text to all blank files in a folder

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I have a folder containing blank files, all the files have a .BAK extension

Now I have a batch script that needs to write arbitrary text top each of the blank files, and I am using the following:

```
for %%a in (C:\Users\david\Documents\*.BAK) do type text >> %%a
```

When I run this script, the command shell tells me that "The system cannot find the specified file", even though there are multiple .BAK files in that folder and they are displayed in the command line output...

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry - Found the answer:

```
FOR /R C:\Users\david\Documents %%f IN (*.DATAPUMP) DO ECHO TEXT >> %%f
```